# Unable to access button defined in file referenced by #include

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I created a website (index.aspx) in which I included my navigation using the include comment

```
<!-- #include virtual ="/include/mainNavigation.aspx" -->
```

Now I want to access a button defined in the navigation.aspx in my index.aspx.vb file in

```
<asp:Button ID="PartA" class="navigationPartButton" runat="server" Text="Part A" />
```

If I want to access this button visual studio tells me that this button is not defined and throws an error.

```
PartA.CssClass = "someCssClass"
```

How do I get this element? I know there is a call getElementByID but on which object do I have to call this?

Comment: Where are you writing that code?

Comment: which code are we talking about at the moment? The PartA.CssClass gets called in the index.aspx.vb file in the Pre_Render sub. the include is loacated in the index.aspx file. The asp button is located in the Navigation.aspx

Comment: Is there a specific reason you didn't move the common code into a user control, which tends to be a more flexible way to approach problems such as this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3207d0e3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx . They are very easy to create and I use them for navigation and menus all the time.

Comment: I suggest not using include virtual and putting the main navigation code inside a custom user control, it will give you a oop model to access the controls easily.